# Match everything after ':' until first non-blank line, then only match everything but a blank line

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby, so I think that's Perl regex. Example:

```
E-mail Address:  user123@gmail.com
Billing Address:

Harry Smith
3423 My Lane
SOME CITY, CA 94105
United States
```

I want to match

```
E-mail Address: user123@gmail.com
```

and

```
Billing Address:

Harry Smith
3423 My Lane
SOME CITY, CA 94105
United States
```

Any ideas?

Here's what I have right now (courtesy of ka):

```
/(.+?):(?:\s+)?([\s\S]+?)\r?\n(?=\r?\n)/g
```

The only issue right now is that it doesn't stop matching user123@gmail.com at that line break

Comment: @Tass Updated with my attempt

Comment: you need the 'Billing Address:' bit also?

Comment: @ka Yup. I'm going to update with what I have so far

Comment: I don't think you can do it without using a group. See my answer below.

Comment: This may be better suited to code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address Pattern with basic regex: `:\s+([a-zA-Z\d'-,\s]*?)\s\s+`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/pU8rY3

Address Pattern with LookArounds: `(?<=Address:\n\n)[a-zA-Z\d'-,\s]*(?=\n\n)`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/zE7nP6

To match everything after a `:` until first non-blank line, then everything until a blank line:
RegEx with capturing: `(?<=:)([\S\s]*)\n\n([\s\S]*)(?=\n\n)`
Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/yN5kM2

Match first line ending in a `:` character then everything until 2 line breaks:
RegExp: `^(.+?):(?:\s+)?([\s\S]+?)\r?\n(?=\r?\n)`
Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jW2hR8

5th update: match **`name: value` or `name: multiline_value`**
RegExp: `^(.+?):(?:[ \t]*(.+)|\s+([\s\S]+?)\r?\n)\r?\n`
Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/jR1iK6

Comment: but this doesn't work if someone puts two spaces in the address (not uncommon with Canadian addresses for example)

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used an address. It doens't have to be an address, it can be anything

Comment: @nneonneo: (about v1) didn't know that, thought `\s` would be better in this case as it includes more than just `\n`. updated with a general pattern not tied to addresses (v3)

Comment: @user1045696 i presume this is what you want (v4) ?

Comment: @kaᵠ Almost there. My question is actually a little more specific. Basically, if there is text on the same line as the : that's after the :, it should end the selection whenever it detects a new line. I'll update the question now

Answer (score 0):

```
/^.*:\n\n([\w\W]*?)\n(?=\n)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/BHEDW4sElE

Basically, this matches the start of the line, then everything up to the colon, then two newlines (a blank line), then a block of text ending in a newline and followed by a blank line.